# Получать запросы по разным путям через 1 php файл

Tags: php

Допустим у меня есть файл /handler.php. Я могу каким-то образом сделать, чтобы все запросы, которые идут на domain.com/handler/param/e4eparam/... и так далее обрабатывались этим /handler.php без создания дополнительных папок?

Answer (score 0):

Да, для веб-сервера Apache можно сделать единую точку входа через .htaccess-файл:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ handler.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: вот автору вопроса будет удивительно, отчего же ваш совет не работает, когда у него какая-то одна из [десятков реализаций http-сервера](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_server_software), но не apache (с его родовой травмой в виде файлов `.htaccess`)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin утончил про Apache

Comment: Да, у меня не апача, но общая суть была в том, можно ли это как-то сделать без задействия веб сервера. Получается нельзя